# prevent unwanted \r \n characters from being added to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that is populated with a SQL call. I'm trying to populate a concatenated string with some of the cells in the row and forward that into an email message body. The problem I'm having is that as cell values are added, each cell value (all text) has a `\r` and `\n` appended to it. I wish to pass the string in the format similar to:

```
"First Name, Last Name, Department..."
"First Name, Last Name, Department..."
etc.
```

What I'm getting is:

```
"\r\n
\First Name\r\n
Last Name \r\n
Department \r\n
```

Do I have to handle the string separately to trim off the unwanted characters, or is there an easier way?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in PayrollGridView.Rows)
{
   HiddenField timecardIdHiddenField = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("TimecardIdHiddenField");
   int timecardId = Convert.ToInt32(timecardIdHiddenField.Value);

   tempString += Regex.Replace((row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty) + ", ";
   tempString += Regex.Replace((row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty) + ":  ";
   tempString += "Regular hours: " + Regex.Replace((row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty) + ", ";
   tempString += "Overtime hours: " + Regex.Replace((row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty) + ", ";

   RadioButtonList radioList = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("ActionRadioButton");

   if (radioList.SelectedItem.Text == "Approve")
   {
      tempString += "Approved." + "<br />";

      SqlHelperClass.ApproveTimecard(timecardId);
   }
   else if (radioList.SelectedItem.Text == "Disapprove")
   {
      approvalList += "DISAPPROVED." + "<br />";
   }

   tempString.Replace("\r\n", " ");
   approvalList += tempString + "<br />";
}
```

Comment: What does the code to add cell values look like?

Comment: `string final = "\r\n First Name\r\n Last Name \r\n Department \r\n".Replace("\r\n",",");` ???

Comment: Are you possible adding lines using a StringBuilder?

Comment: added my approach above.  Thanks

Comment: `approvalList += tempString.Replace("\r\n", " "); + "<br />";` in your code the resut of your replace is gone because you don't store the result. Remember that Strings are immutable.

Comment: duh, thanks.  Been a while since I've manipulated strings, but should not have forgotten that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a StringBuilder to append the contents of each cell, make sure you use Append and not AppendLine. Similarly, if you are using a StringWriter, use Write instead of WriteLine.